# Getting Message with Gmail API

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, gmail-api

Today I have been playing around with the Gmail API. Currently I am able to use GTLQueryForUserMessagesList to get a list of message ids. Now what Im trying to do is use GTLQueryForUserMessagesGet to get a single message which requires the id of a message but Im not sure where I specify the id of the message.

Here is my code for the Query

```
func fetchMessage(id : Int) {
    let query = GTLQueryGmail.queryForUsersMessagesGet() as! GTLQueryProtocol
    service.executeQuery(query, delegate: self, didFinishSelector: "displayResultWithTicket:finishedWithObject:error:")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the header in `GTLQuery.h`. You need to put the parameters into an attribute of the returned query object:

```
- (GTL_NSDictionaryOf(NSString *, NSString *) *)urlQueryParameters;
```

Comment: Im not sure if I quite understand. Could you give a quick example?

Answer (score 0):

From [SwiftLang.eu](https://swiftlang.eu/community/5014-gmail-api-request-a-message/):

> You should add query parameters like: `query.urlQueryParameters = ["identifier": id]`